# Android Activity and its Fragment subscribe to the same event

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, event-bus

What happens if a Fragment and its Activity subscribe to the same event? Will both be notified when the event is fired?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if both are **subscribe** the **event** and both are **alive**.Then both will be notify.